# Email won't go through when deployed in django

Tags: django, heroku

I have a contact form in my django app. I get the email when I try locally. When I deployed to heroku I don't get the email when someone fills out a form. They get a server error. What settings do I need to change for this?

Comment: What does the server error tell you?

Comment: What kind of error? Do you have logs?

Comment: I have debug as false. So it just gives me a server 500 error. Do I need to purchase an add on for email service to work? currently I don't have any add ons

Comment: @tranttrum see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp

Comment: Is there a way to do it without purchasing the add on?

Comment: @tranttrum could you show your email settings?

Comment: EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'username@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'foo'
EMAIL_PORT = 587